# Short story about old man and boy shamans in conquistador era?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, magic

Okay, I thought this was a Ray Bradbury but I haven’t been able to find it again. In this short story, and old man and little boy are in a jungle overlooking a beach. The old man is teaching the little boy how to look through the eyes of an animal, specifically a bird. The boy initially struggles with snapping out of the animal’s mind. The boy watches the beach through the eyes of an eagle or gull and sees men in armor-conquistadors or crusaders- landing on the beach. At the end there’s kind of a dread, they know their world is going to collapse, and they fade quietly back into the jungle as the men on the beach prepare for battle. They might have shape shifting abilities as well. I thought the title might have some sort of Aztec word as a name. Anyone know the title or author?

Comment: Crusaders or conquistadors? I could be wrong but I don't think any of the Crusader-Jihadi wars were fought in jungles, so if you're sure about the jungle, it's probably conquistadors. Did the shaman's threatened way of life involve human sacrifice?

Comment: I think you’re right- I’m pretty sure it was conquistadors, but it was a while since I read the story. I don’t believe there was any major references to human sacrifice, but there might have been something about ziggurats? They might have shapeshifted into some kind of jungle creatures as well.

Comment: @user14111 - By the way, there were not really "Crusader-Jihadi wars." The term "Jihadi" refers to modern armed movements that seek to impose political interpretations of Islam. Even if one were to anachronistically extrapolate it back to vaguely analogous movements in the past, the Crusaders were actually fighting against established Islamic monarchies with little interest in imposing Islam outside of their own territories.